# cross-browser CSS neat solution suggestions?

Tags: css, cross-browser

In your opinion, What would be a neat way of doing cross browser css (IE7, Safari, Chrome, Firefox).

Considering that is a huge web app, and this has a big main css file, and some many other css files.

Conditional Css? and using a diferent css for each browser?
Any known tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, if you've written good CSS to start with, then the only browser that will need any significant remedial work will be IE (prior to v9).

For all other current browsers, standard CSS should work without any changes. In fact, even for IE, if you make sure your page loads in standards mode and not quirks mode, then IE should behave itself for most basic CSS.

The obvious exception to that is if a given browser doesn't support a feature that you're trying to use. In this case, you should use feature detection rather than browser detection. This is a more robust solution, because the odds are good that a new version of that browser will be released relatively soon which will support that feature.

For feature detection, I recommend [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

A few features that are missing in IE such as CSS rounded corners can be fixed using hacks like [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/), which allows you to use standard CSS code for these features for all browsers including IE.

For those niggly things in IE which simply can't be dealt with any other way, you should use [IE's conditional comments feature](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to include an IE-specific stylesheet.

If you have CSS code which still doesn't work cross browser after that, then you're probably doing something wrong with your stylesheets -- please post it here and ask for help with the specific problem.

Comment: Yeah, IE7 is the ones giving a headache :-(. At the moment it works on any browser except IE7, therefore there is a need to find a solution that is neat.

Comment: @Amra - conditional comments it is, then. See the link in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way is to use Conditional comments for IE:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="styles/IE7styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<! [endif]-->
```

Seeing as the other browsers are behaving as you expect, you can just use a IE7 specific stylesheet :)

Comment: I agree, I was checking that there wasn't a nicer way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: There is a jQuery plugin called the CSS browser detector that once plugged in allows you to select the browsers from the stylesheet itself but as far as I remember it relies on browser sniffing so it's not the cleanest. Conditional comments are the best way. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't start worrying about browser compatibility until you have some browser compatibility problems.

The modern browsers generally all work in the same or similar ways, so if you do have issues they're likely to be with IE. What generally works best is creating an IE-specific stylesheet that you include using conditional comments, after your main CSS, that allows you to workaround any IE-specific issues. But try and get it all working with one first.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have real problems, while dealing with different IE versions, so i'd go with conditional comments loading appropriate css files to the different browsers.

I usually have a "main" css file and then target IE versions with conditional comments.